# Navigation Handling with PHP

Tags: php, css, navigation, menuitem, navigationcontroller

I have stuck in a code. I am building a website which has lots of inner page. i include "sidebar.php" and place my side navigation in this file.

```
<div class="side-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Calls</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="record-calls.php">Call Record</a></li>
                        <li><a href="call-logs.php">Call Logs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="live-call-intercept.php">Live Call Intercept</a></li>
                        <li><a href="voicemail.php">Voicemail</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">SMS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="sms-feature.php">SMS Feature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="redirect-sms.php">Redirect SMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
             </div>
```

Now i want to high light "record-calls" li when "record-calls.php" page is open and other list don't show any backgrounds.

There is only 1 sidebar.php which is including in every page.

Comment: place a variable to track the page

Comment: Track the record-calls.php and put a condition if the url contains record-calls.php then make that li highlighted

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use if condition

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'record-calls.php'))
{
   //highlight it
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods you can use to highlight current page on the sidebar menu. I don't know your structure. In this case, I would suggest get the current URL by php and check if, for example, record-calls is included in it or not. Something like that:

```
<li <?php if(strpos('record-calls', $current_url) !== false) echo "class='current'"; ?>><a href="record-calls.php">Call Record</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set some unique class on your `<body>` for a given page and use it to style the relevant part of your menu.

Exemples (not pretty, but I use your actual HTML) :

```
.record-calls side-nav li li:first-child { /* highlight styles */ } 
.call-logs side-nax li li:first-child + li { /* highlight styles */ }
```

etc...